# Read correctly an HTML with urllib2 and python

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I opened this link "[http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1](http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n:1)" with urllib2 and i was trying to fetch the next page link (href="/s/ref=lp_1_pg_2?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1376769633") avaible in the html text. Howevar the read() function keeps on reading this part as (href="/s?rh=n%3A1&page=2") who doesn't work.
There's any way to make the read function read the link correctly?

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: I just did this and printed the result:
response=urllib2.urlopen(link)
html = response.read()

The link that i got for the next page I got it by seeing the source code of the page

Comment: are you want next page url?

Comment: Yeah, the one in the source code associated to the "next page" button. When urllib reads it it reads it wrong :/

Comment: I couldn't find either (href="/s/ref=lp_1_pg_2?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1376769633" or href="/s?rh=n%3A1&page=2" in the HTML when I got it with urllib.request, or when I looked at the source in with my browser.

Answer (score 2):

It does it because you don't have headers. I tried:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = Browser()

html_page = browser.open("http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
link = soup.find("a", {"title" : "Next Page"})
print link
```

Output:

```
<a title="Next Page" id="pagnNextLink" class="pagnNext" href="/s?rh=n%3A1&amp;page=2">
<span id="pagnNextString">Next Page</span>
<span class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"></span>
</a>
```

Then I added headers:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = Browser()

browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0\
    (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')]

html_page = browser.open("http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
link = soup.find("a", {"title" : "Next Page"})
print link
```

Output:

```
<a title="Next Page" id="pagnNextLink" class="pagnNext" href="/s/ref=lp_1_pg_2/177-4872792-4084836?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1&amp;page=2&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1376771097">
<span id="pagnNextString">Next Page</span>
<span class="srSprite pagnNextArrow"></span>
</a>
```

So just add header information like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385262/how-do-i-send-a-custom-header-with-urllib2-in-a-http-request)

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1")
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0\
            (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
            Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')

html_page = urllib2.urlopen(req)

if html_page.getcode() == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    link = soup.find("a", {"title" : "Next Page"})
    print link['href']

else:
    print "Error loading page"
```

Output:

```
/s/ref=lp_1_pg_2/176-2670743-2970243?rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A1&page=2&ie=UTF8&qid=1376771750
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
import urllib2
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        href = []
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag == "a":
                for attr in attrs:
                    if attr[0] == "href" and 'page' in attr[1] and 'rh' in attr[1]:
                        self.href.append(attr[1])


    def _get(url):
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html = response.read()
        parser = MyHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(html.decode('utf-8'))
        href = parser.href
        print href

    _get('http://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1')
```