# Using urllib2 to make a post request with headers

Tags: python, http-post, urllib2

I want to send a post request to a URL with specific data and header types. using these two links I found that how to do that, but it's not working:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693931/python-post-request
[How do I send a custom header with urllib2 in a HTTP Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385262/how-do-i-send-a-custom-header-with-urllib2-in-a-http-request)
This is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://clients6.google.com/rpc'
values = [
    {"method": "pos.plusones.get",
     "id": "p",
     "params": {
                "nolog": True,
                "id": "http://www.newswhip.com",
                "source": "widget",
                "userId": "@viewer",
                "groupId": "@self"
                },
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "key": "p",
     "apiVersion": "v1"
    }]
headers = {"Content-type" : "application/json:"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

I can get result with these values in Postman Rest Client. but after execution of this code the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Developer Center/Republishan/republishan2/republishan2/test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1312, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

I've also tried to use dictionary instead of list like this:

```
values = {"method": "pos.plusones.get",
     "id": "p",
     "params": {
                "nolog": True,
                "id": "http://www.newswhip.com",
                "source": "widget",
                "userId": "@viewer",
                "groupId": "@self"
                },
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "key": "p",
     "apiVersion": "v1"
    }
```

It executes the script but the result contains error:

```
{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Unable to parse json","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Unable to parse json"}]}}
```

As I told, I can execute script with list instead of dictionary with Postman Rest Client.
Look at the results in Postman:
[image]
What should I do?

Comment: `values` should be dict not list. Try `values = {"method": "pos.plusones.get", ...., "apiVersion": "v1"}`

Comment: question updated, it worked but the result is an error.

Comment: Some server error, I assume. Check that the values you are sending are correctly formatted and the server expects it in the same fashion.

Comment: Man these values are working with a Rest Client! I think an additional configuration in urllib needed.

Comment: @sk11 Look at the picture in my question

Comment: Just a wild guess, why u have the extra colon after `application/json` in `headers = {"Content-type" : "application/json:"}`?

Comment: @sk11 I removed the colon, nothing happened, is it possible to copy and run my code? I know it's an over expectation but I really need that solution from an expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like urllib.urlencode doesn't understand nested dicts:

```
     In [38]: urllib.urlencode({"a": "asas", "df": {"sds": 123, "t": "fgfg"}})
     Out[38]: 'a=asas&df=%7B%27t%27%3A+%27fgfg%27%2C+%27sds%27%3A+123%7D'
```

Or your example:

```
     In [41]: urllib.urlencode(values)
     Out[41]: 'jsonrpc=2.0&apiVersion=v1&id=p&params=%7B%27nolog%27%3A+True%2C+%27source%27%3A+%27widget%27%2C+%27userId%27%3A+%27%40viewer%27%2C+%27id%27%3A+%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newswhip.com%27%2C+%27groupId%27%3A+%27%40self%27%7D&key=p&method=pos.plusones.get'
```

See, braces in "params" gets messed up.

I'm not sure how to cure this using urllib. So i'll recommend requests library.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

in short it will look like this (you'll need to install requests library first, for example using pip: `pip install requests`):

```
     import requests
     import json

     url = 'https://clients6.google.com/rpc'
     values = {
         "method": "pos.plusones.get",
         "id": "p",
         "params": {
                    "nolog": True,
                    "id": "http://www.newswhip.com",
                    "source": "widget",
                    "userId": "@viewer",
                    "groupId": "@self"
                   },
          "jsonrpc": "2.0",
          "key": "p",
          "apiVersion": "v1"
     }
     headers = {"content-type" : "application/json"}

     req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(values), headers=headers)
     print req.text
```

It works for me.

Comment: It was all about this snippet that made the difference for me "data=json.dumps(values)" as I even did not have a dict JSON but a simple object and it was failing to send it properly using requests. Thanks!