# Python 2.7 - Batch downloading json files using urllib2 - [Errno 10054] existing connection forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, download

I am using the below code to batch download a text list of json files from the web.  The links aren't standardized and can be https or http and can end with '.json' or not.

```
def save_json(url):
  import os
  filename = url.replace('/','').replace(':','') .replace('.','|').replace('|json','.json').replace('|JSON','.json').replace('|','').replace('?','').replace('=','').replace('&','')
  path = "U:/location/json"
  fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
  import urllib2
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  webContent = response.read()
  f = open(fullpath, 'w')
  f.write(webContent)
  f.close()


f = open('U:/location/index_dl.txt')
p = f.read()
url_list = p.split('\n') #here's where \n is the line break delimiter that can be changed
for url in url_list:
  save_json(url)
```

Every so often I get the error:

> Errno 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

[image]

**Question**:  Does anyone know of another way to batch download a list of json links from the web, or have a way to handle this error as it happens?

Thanks in advance!
SJB

Comment: print url on screen and try it in browser - maybe you create incorect url. Or maybe you need some HTTP headers (like `user-agent`) because server checks it.

Comment: I think urllib2 is attempting another request over the connection that was reset on the server. Sending HTTP header "Connection: Keep-Alive" should help. Check this question for how to do this with urllib2 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385262/how-do-i-send-a-custom-header-with-urllib2-in-a-http-request

Comment: You need to provide a *fake* user agent to a web server to deceive it.