# BeautifulSoup Webscraping Errors

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a site and I keep getting the error messages below.  I have tried this script on other websites and it works fine.  I have searched to find a solution and can't seem to find one that works.  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "math-webscrape.py", line 8, in <module>
    uClient = urlopen(math_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Here is my script

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

math_url = 'https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/'

#opening up connection and grabbing page
uClient = urlopen(math_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs info for each textbook
containers = page_soup.findAll("p",{"class":"approved-book"})

data = []
for container in containers:
item = {}
item['type'] = "Textbook"
item['title'] = container.a.text
item['author'] =container.a.findNextSibling(text=True).strip()
item['link'] = container.a["href"]
item['source'] = "College Open Textbooks"
data.append(item) # add the item to the list

with open("./json/cot.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a header to get the response. You can try like below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

math_url = 'https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/'

res = Request(math_url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
uClient = urlopen(res)
page_html = uClient.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

The targeted website is obviously blocking the User-Agent of urllib.

You can set a custom User-Agent to bypass this: [How do I send a custom header with urllib2 in a HTTP Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385262/how-do-i-send-a-custom-header-with-urllib2-in-a-http-request)

Answer (score 0):

This website seems to block the default python `User-Agent`. You can disguise yourself like this:

```
import urllib.request

math_url = 'https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/'

req = urllib.request.Request(
    math_url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

uClient = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```